# Reading Formatted Input from File with fscanf and sscanf

Tags: c

I have to read a file that has this form

```
Aalborg%Denmark%
Aba%Nigeria%
Abadan%Iran%
Abaetetuba%Brazil%
Abakan%Russia%
```

I am using this batch of code (printf added for testing):

```
    char *key, *country, *string, *endofl;
    key = malloc (25*(sizeof(char)));
    country = malloc (35 * sizeof(char));
    string = malloc (60* sizeof(char));
    if (fgets(string, 60, from) != NULL) {      
        endofl = strchr(string, '\n');
        printf("%s\n", endofl);
        if (endofl != NULL)
            *(endofl) = '\0';
        sscanf(string, "%s%%%s%%", key, country);
    if (key != NULL && country != NULL) {
        printf("------%s|%s------\n", string, key); //Elem->key
        strcpy(Elem->key, key); 
        printf("------%s|%s------\n", Elem->country, country);
        strcpy(Elem->country, country);
    printf("Helooo\n");
}
```

I understand my problem is somewhere in sscanf (propably the formatting) because it seems that the function 'stores' the whole line on key.

Any help?

Comment: You should probably check for `key` and `country` not being `NULL` before trying to use the pointers.

Comment: `if (key != NULL && country != NULL) {` --> `if (2 == sscanf(string, "%24[^%]%%%34[^%]", key, country)) {` . `NULL` check Prior to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that the `"%s"` format code

> matches a character string (a sequence of non-whitespace characters)

So the first `"%s"` in your format matches *all* characters in the line, as there is no whitespace between the fields. The pattern matching doesn't work you expect.

Instead you have to use the `"%["` format:

```
sscanf(string, "%[^%]%%%[^%]", key, country);
```

The above format string matches all characters *except* the `'%'` character, then pattern matches the `'%'` to discard it, then again matches all except the trailing `'%'`.

---

Also note that if `scanf` fails to match all your formats, it will not set the pointers to `NULL`, and might not even write anything at all to the provided strings (letting them be uninitialized). Instead you should check the returned value of `scanf`. It should match the number of format codes, two in your case, or there was a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really clarifies it!